# SQL queries with views and subqueries

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
select nid, avg, std from sView1
  where sid = 4891
    and nid in (select distinct nid from tblref where rid = 799)
    and oidin (select distinct oid from tblref where rid = 799)
    and anscount > 3
```

This is a query I'm currently trying to run. And running it like this takes about 3-4 seconds. However, if I replace the "4891" value with a subquery saying `(select distinct sid from tblref where rid = 799)` the procedure just hangs, even though the subquery only returns one `sid`.

The query is supposed to return a dataset with averages (avg) and standard deviations (std) over a resultset which is calculated through nested views in sView1. This dataset is then run through another view to get some top-level averages and stdevs.

The averages may need to include more than 1 `sid` (sid identifies a dataset).

It's difficult describing it more without revealing codebase and codestructure that shouldn't be revealed ;)

Can anyone suggest why the query hangs when trying to use the subquery? (The code is rebuilt from originally using nested cursors, since I have been told that cursors are the work of the devil, and nested cursors may make me sterile)

Comment: I don't think an answer is possible, as you don't show all the queries. Try to simplify but don't hide the code!

Comment: `oidin` should probably be `oid in`. Try to always copy/paste your code completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Exists returns as soon as it finds a matching condition, select distinct will require going through the dataset and optionally sorting it to remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT nid,avg,std from sView1 AS SV
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TblRef AS TR WHERE sv.sid = Tr.sid AND Sv.nid = tr.nid AND sv.oid = tr.oid AND tr.rid = 799)
AND ansCount>3
```

Also, it is pretty difficult to provide a meaningful answer without access to query plans and table structures. So DDL and sample data will definitely help.

Comment: That isn't the same semantics as the original query. Your query enforces that the matching tr.oid, tr.nid and Tr.sid should all be from the same row.

Comment: If you look at his original post - select distinct sid from .. , then the query does look semantically similar.

Comment: Similar, but not the same - as Martin observes, the original query did not mandate that nid and oid had to be on the same row on TblRef.

Comment: The OP should clarify what he is after.